# What's the meaning of "release" configuration when you deploy?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, release, provisioning

So, after several hours of reading the Apple walkthrough I finally managed to deploy my app in my iPod, under development configuration (easy one) and under distribution configuration (a pain), even AdHoc seems to be working without errors.

So... what's the purpose of the "release" configuration?, I only used development and distribution (adhoc and appstore provisionings), seems like Im missing something...

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at 'Project' -> 'Edit Project Settings'. You'll notice that you can have different sets of settings for different configurations. A great use for this would be to set your distribution certificate to the release configuration, and your development certificate to your debug configuration; solving future issues with App Store submission.

You can also separate code at compile time with flags like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
NSLog(@"Debug build");
#else
NSLog(@"Other build");
#endif
```

Comment: Oh, I see, so there is no "magic" behind the release configuration, its just like any other configuration.

Comment: @Artemix: Correct. In my release configurations I sometimes add "NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS" (if it's not already there) to tell the compiler to ignore all the instances of `NSAssert()` I used in debugging. Then I don't have to manually strip these out of my code when I release.

Comment: well, there's a bit of magic. By default, obviously the debug flags are off, and the optimization mode is a bit higher than debug. But that's about it

Comment: I think you meant `#ifdef DEBUG` otherwise your preprocessor condition is flipped.